# Gunicorn with sync workers and async endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi, gunicorn

When we create a gunicorn using 2 workers and concurrently hit 20 requests then up to certain time requests are executed on different workers but then the requests start executing on the same worker sequentially, why gunicorn show such behavior? Since in async a single thread is created for each worker and that request is executed using that thread, although the core of my cpu is unused still the worker remains empty and the rest of the requests are executed sequentially through one worker.
The endpoint of API is async and the workers are synchronous.
This is the console result.

```
@app.post("/apii2")
async def processing(requestJson: Dict):
        print("we here man")
        print(os.getpid(), " ------------------  ",requestJson["id"]," -------------------- ", datetime.now())
        time.sleep(eval(requestJson["id"]))
        print("peace out")
```

Output:-

we here man

we here man

35707  ------------------   15  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:37:35.587476

35706  ------------------   10  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:37:35.587476

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   16  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:37:45.600518

peace out

we here man

35707  ------------------   19  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:37:50.603958

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   15  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:38:01.617591

peace out

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   18  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:38:16.629669

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   5  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:38:34.645926

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   17  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:38:39.649604

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   21  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:38:56.667146

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   10  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:39:17.688973

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   19  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:39:27.700038

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   20  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:39:46.717574

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   16  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:40:06.727625

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   21  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:40:22.741164

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   20  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:40:43.762873

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   22  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:41:03.783833

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   5  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:41:25.805320

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   22  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:41:30.809944

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   18  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:41:52.829541

peace out

we here man

35706  ------------------   17  --------------------  2024-01-22 13:42:10.845286

peace out

I was expecting that 2 requests at a would be executed parallelly.

Comment: Your code is not async compatible; you're calling `time.sleep` which isn't async - so you have two workers that are kept busy with `time.sleep` that never give up control. async does not make your code run in parallel automagically, it requires you to cooperate - so in that case, you'll have to swap it out with `await asyncio.sleep(...)` to make it async compatible.

Comment: @MatsLindh time.sleep() is just to block the code if I use await asyncio.sleep(...) then this will suspend the coroutine, the workers are synchronous. Even instead of time.sleep() if I use a for loop for a long time it shows the same behavior.

Comment: A for-loop won't give up any time for other code to run either, so if you have two workers with synchronous endpoints (defined as `async` in your code, which means that they assume that you're using async compatible code inside) - so if you have two workers, that have their async event loops blocked, you won't be able to run more than two things at the same time. Two workers, two blocked event loops => two requests at the same time. Either use async compatible code or don't define your endpoint as async (which means the code will run in a threadpool instead).

Comment: @MatsLindh that is the question you said that 2 requests should be executed parallelly but if you look at the output only up to a certain time 2 requests are executed parallelly then the rest of the requests are executed sequentially on the same worker, whereas if you see the logs the other worker also became free at a certain point, but still all the requests are executed on the same worker.

Comment: @MatsLindh the endpoints are async but the uvicorn workers are synchronous

Comment: Please edit to make more obvious in which way this question is different from the proposed duplicate. Explicitly point out the difference if necessary. If you convince me I will vote to reopen, but better convince the user who closed (they have a special privilege here, but that is good for you, because the way they earned it means they should be very able to understand detailed reasoning in this technical area. ... I am not, sorry.)

Comment: @MatsLindh can you please help

Comment: @RishuTyagi Not much more to say, sorry - it might also be caused by how you're sending the requests; in general, I'd start by looking at the requests being made to make sure they're actually being sent as you expect, then how gunicorn distributes its tasks across workers (and look at which workers are available and their status while you're sending the requests). But if you want to get all twenty requests to execute in parallel, you'll either need to drop the `async` keyword on the tasks and let the threadpool handle it, use 20 workers or use async compatible code.

Comment: @MatsLindh I made requests using a .sh file with 20 curl commands and I want 2 requests to be executed parallelly not 20, since I only have 2 workers

Comment: I would suggest reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) very carefuly and make sure you apprehend everything explained in that answer, e.g., the concept of `async` / `await`, and how the event loop (of each worker) might get blocked, as well as use the provided code in that answer to send concurrent requests to your API, in order to test it (or make sure that whatever tool you are using is sending the requests concurrently or in parallel)

Comment: @Chris Using & in .sh file for requests to be parallel. Will read your answer

Comment: In addition to the linked answer above, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804) helpful as well.